# Firestore realtime update is not working on recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using cloud firestore to populate recyclerview.

However, the realtime update is not working, changes are shown after I restarting the app. I also added pagination on recyclerview. Document addition and modification are only shows when restarting the app.

To load my post:

```
private fun loadMorePost() {
    val nextQuery = shopsCollection
            .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .startAfter(lastVisible)
            .limit(3)

    nextQuery.addSnapshotListener({ documentSnapshots, e ->
        if (!documentSnapshots.isEmpty) {

            lastVisible = documentSnapshots.documents[documentSnapshots.size() - 1]
            for (doc in documentSnapshots) {

                    val shop = doc.toObject(Shop::class.java)
                    shopList.add(shop)

                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

                }
            }
    })
}
```

onStart():

```
public override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    val isUserFirstTime = java.lang.Boolean.valueOf(Utility.readSharedSetting(applicationContext, Utility.PREF_USER_FIRST_TIME, "true"))
    val introIntent = Intent(this@MainActivity, OnBoardActivity::class.java)
    introIntent.putExtra(Utility.PREF_USER_FIRST_TIME, isUserFirstTime)
    if (isUserFirstTime) {
        startActivity(introIntent)
        finish()
    } else if (user == null) {
        startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, WelcomeActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    } else if (!isUserFirstTime) {
        val firstQuery = shopsCollection.orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(3)
        firstQuery.addSnapshotListener({ documentSnapshots, e ->
            lastVisible = documentSnapshots.documents[documentSnapshots.size() - 1]

            for (doc in documentSnapshots) {
                showFabButton()
                val blogPost = doc.toObject(Shop::class.java)
                shopList.add(blogPost)

                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
              }
          })
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Is your `addSnapshotListener` when there is an update? E.g. if you add some logging in there or set a breakpoint, does it log/trigger when there is an update?

Comment: But it doesn't works,  The changes are showns only restarting the app

Comment: @user8209569 that ist what Frank is trying to figure out. It may be that the Listener is not called, the list is not altered correctly or the changes may not be correctly reflected from the list to the view after an update.

Comment: Please post your adapter and the way you are setting the adapter in your `RecyclerView`.

Comment: P.S. You are calling notifyDatasetChanged after each item adding. Move it out of the for loop

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the changes to the Database you refer to are deletions:

In your Code you add new items but don't remove possible deletions. So changing your code to the following should work:

```
nextQuery.addSnapshotListener({ documentSnapshots, e ->
    if (!documentSnapshots.isEmpty) {
        shopList.clear()
        lastVisible = documentSnapshots.documents[documentSnapshots.size() - 1]
        for (doc in documentSnapshots) {
                val shop = doc.toObject(Shop::class.java)
                shopList.add(shop)
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
})
```